# View filtered by a Date field's value being in "last month" shows July content on July 31

Tags: 7, views, datetime

A View is filtered by a Date field's value.  The Date field's month must be last month in order to match the filter.

[image: Filter setting]

On every day except July 31 it would return results from last month.  It should have returned results matching June.  We have tried "-1 month" but that didn't work either.

Why on July 31 does it jump ahead a month?

Comment: May be problem in date.timezone settings in your php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 'last day of last month' or 'first day of last month'.

Comment: First day of last month did it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding "-1 months" relative value. you can get any month records just need to use + - no. of month to get previous or next months data.

[image]

[image]